# compute an integral using scipy where the integrand is a product with parameters coming from a (arbitrarily long) list

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I want to solve the coupon collector's problem in the general case (with varying possibilities for each coupon) using Flajolet's formula that I found  on wikipedia (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). According to the formula I have to compute an integral where the integrand is a product. I'm using scipy.integrad.quad and lambda-notation to integrate. Problem is that the number of factors in the integrand is not fixed (has parameters coming from a list). When I try to multiply the integrand factors I get an error, since I cannot multiply formal expressions, seemingly. But if I don't, I don't know to get the integration variable x in.

I found ways to integrate a product, if there are, for example, only 2 factors. And it doesn't seem to involve double integration or some such. Can anyone please help (I'm quite new to this stuff)?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
....
def compute_general_case(p_list):
    integrand = 1
    for p in p_list:
        integrand_factor = lambda x: 1 - np.exp(-p * x)
        integrand *= integrand_factor
    integrand = 1 - integrand
    erg = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, np.inf)
    print(erg)
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If your formula is correct, or if there exists some out-of-the-box package that handles the arbitrary length case?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your comment (since I'm new to this site). Mstaino has already answered my question meanwhile. The formula was from Wikipedia and (very presumably) correct. What I didn't know was how to code it.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the integration function with an arbitrary number of arguments, provided you pass them to `quad` using `args=`:

```
def integrand(x, *p_list):
    p_list = np.asarray(p_list)
    return 1 - np.product(1 - np.exp(-x * p_list))   #don't need to for-loop a product in numpy

result, abserr = quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=[1,1,1,1])
print(result, abserr)
>> 2.083333333333334 2.491001112400493e-10
```

For more information, see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)

Comment: Thanks very much. Still have to work out the details in my head and play around with it a bit, but it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for addressing this question: as a follow on to @Mstaino's answer, you don't even need the `args` as you can pass them into the function via a closure:

```
def coupon_collector_expected_samples(probs):
    """
    Find the expected number of samples before all "coupons" (with a
    non-uniform probability mass) are "collected".

    Args:
        probs (ndarray): probability mass for each unique item

    References:
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem
        https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i2p33/pdf
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539128/scipy-integrand-is-product

    Example:
        >>> import numpy as np
        >>> import ubelt as ub
        >>> # Check EV of samples for a non-uniform distribution
        >>> probs = [0.38, 0.05, 0.36, 0.16, 0.05]
        >>> ev = coupon_collector_expected_samples(probs)
        >>> print('ev = {}'.format(ub.repr2(ev, precision=4)))
        ev = 30.6537

        >>> # Use general solution on a uniform distribution
        >>> probs = np.ones(4) / 4
        >>> ev = coupon_collector_expected_samples(probs)
        >>> print('ev = {}'.format(ub.repr2(ev, precision=4)))
        ev = 8.3333

        >>> # Check that this is the same as the solution for the uniform case
        >>> import sympy
        >>> n = len(probs)
        >>> uniform_ev = float(sympy.harmonic(n) * n)
        >>> assert np.isclose(ev, uniform_ev)
    """
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import integrate
    probs = np.asarray(probs)
    # Philippe Flajolet's generalized expected value integral
    def _integrand(t):
        return 1 - np.product(1 - np.exp(-probs * t))
    ev, abserr = integrate.quad(func=_integrand, a=0, b=np.inf)
    return ev
```

You can also see that my implementation is faster:

```
import timerit
ti = timerit.Timerit(100, bestof=10, verbose=2)

probs = np.random.rand(100)

from scipy import integrate
def orig_method(p_list):
    def integrand(x, *p_list):
        p_list = np.asarray(p_list)
        return 1 - np.product(1 - np.exp(-x * p_list))
    result, abserr = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=p_list)
    return result

ti = timerit.Timerit(100, bestof=10, verbose=2)
for timer in ti.reset('orig_implementation'):
    with timer:
        orig_method(probs)

for timer in ti.reset('my_implementation'):
    with timer:
        coupon_collector_expected_samples(probs)

# Results:
# Timed orig_implementation for: 100 loops, best of 10
#     time per loop: best=7.267 ms, mean=7.954 ± 0.5 ms
# Timed my_implementation for: 100 loops, best of 10
#     time per loop: best=5.618 ms, mean=5.648 ± 0.0 ms
```